# The caller doesnot have permission error while logging in to google api console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-console

I'm trying to log in to the Google API console. But I'm getting the error as shown in the below image. Please help me to solve this.

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The caller does not have permission. As shown in fig.

Comment: If you click OK, can you then select a "project" in the top bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) says you can check two things:

- Select the [project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects) before accessing the GCP console menu.
- The user that you are logging on GCP has the corrects [roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-management-roles) and [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) for use the service.